# Could a Rogue/Sorceror multiclass work this purpose?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization

We are playing for fun with a friend and I wanted to create a lv 4-6 character to do this gameplay:

It's a rogue, able to go stealth easily and prepare flame or strong magical arrows so that you could take advantage of:

- sneak attack, with advantage of the double d20 for hit because the character start hidden
- is difficult to attack him because he's hidden all the time

I'm not very fond of all character creating spells, talents or similar.. Was thinking about multiclassing a LV 5 (Rogue 3, Sorcerer 2) or LV 6 (Rogue 3 Sorcerer 3)

Let's say I'm able to hide my character as first move in the battle. If my character start casting a spell the verbal and gesture components could break the "hidden status".

**Is possible to create a build, and what spells / player setup I can use to achieve powerful piercing/fire/magical attacks with a bow keeping my hidden / rogue traits ?**

I tried to use a total of **77 points** divided in:

**STR: 11 (+0)**
**DEX: 18 (+4)**
**CON: 14 (+2)**
**INT: 10 (+0)**
**WIS: 10 (+0)**
**CHA: 14 (+2)**

I know it's a bit powerplay lame character but it's for fun ;)

Comment: The point buy math is confusing.  Point buy for level 1 yields (from a 27 point buy) either  15, 15, 15, 8,8,8 for 69, or 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13 (75) or 14 14 14, 10 10 10 for 72.  Then add the +2 for the ASI at 4th level if the character has 4 levels in one class or the other.  Otherwise, No ASI.   So you point buy is either 77, 71, or 74 depending on the model your DM is using. Have you discussed this with your DM?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast lol you right added :) I'm not sure about the model he is using but he said to assign 77 as total, and I'm with a racial +2 DEX given by being an halfling.

Comment: Please explain how the points assignment works.  Did you start with 75 total points and then add (whatever) racial bonus? Are feats allowed?  We understand that multiclassing is allowed.  Does your  build account for an ASI if you use a 4/2 split (one more feat or +2 points to distribute?)  Please clear that up.  Also, please choose total character levels: the difference between 5 and 6 if you go 3/3 or 4/2 can be substantial in unlocking class skills and features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is it possible to create a Rogue character that has powerful piercing/fire/magical attacks with a ranged weapon, while still maintaining the Rogue's sneakiness?**

### Certainly, but I wouldn't advise multi-classing into Sorcerer.

First of all, as soon as you attack, you reveal your position. You can try to hide but smart or perceptive enemies can still figure out your general position. Not even rogues remain invisible forever.

Then, you can either take the **Arcane Trickster Rogue** (meaning you don't have to multi-class) and you get Wizard spells. Or multi-class into something else. The Arcane Trickster, as far as I can see, doesn't have many *arrow attack empowering* spells, but it doesn't make you lose class-progression (remember that *Sneak Attack*'s damage is based on your Rogue level), and it gives you spells like **Find Familiar**, which can help proc your Sneak Attack. Multi-classing into Sorcerer doesn't give you many spells for attack empowerment.

My best recommendation for your goal is to multi-class into **Ranger** (or even make a Ranger and multi-class into Rogue), and boost Wisdom instead of Charisma. You get spells like **Hunter's Mark**, **Ensnaring Strike** and **Hail of Thorns**, all of which benefit from your ranged attacks. Ranger/Rogue is quite a popular combination, mixing sneak attacks with the ranger's skills.

### Example:

- Thief Rogue 3 / Hunter Ranger 3
- Archery: +2 on attack rolls with ranged weapons
- 3 level-1 spells (**Hunter's Mark**, **Ensnaring Strike** and **Hail of Thorns**)
- Colossus Slayer: extra 1d8 damage against creatures that are hurt
- Sneak Attack: 2d6 extra damage when hidden or allies nearby
- Fast Hands: apply poison or use healing potion (or just use Cunning Action to hide, disengage, dash) or something else as a bonus action

---

So, assuming 18 DEX, your rolls with a bow have a +9 attack modifier and deal

> [Longbow 1d8]+[Sneak Attack 2d6]+[Colossus Slayer 1d8]+[Poison 1d6 (may vary)]+[Hunter's Mark 1d6]+[Hail of Thorns 1d10]+[Dexterity 4]

This damage assumes ideal conditions, of course. This happens only if

- attack lands
- creature is hurt
- ally is nearby or you are hidden
- you have poison arrows and target fails poison ST
- you cast Hunter's Mark previously
- creature fails Hail of Thorns ST

And you can only use 3 spells a day, and poison isn't cheap...

Comment: Thanks, you can provide also an example of a Ranger/Rogue with this empowered ranged attacks?

Comment: I'm assuming he will power-build and pick a race with +2 DEX racial, but I've edited for clarity.

Comment: @BlueMoon93 how are you getting 18 point-buy and 2 racial, when point-buy caps at 15?

Comment: @nitsua60 It does? Had no idea. Since I saw OP with 18 DEX, I just assumed he could distribute his 77 points anyway he wanted. I'll edit this out

Comment: @BlueMoon93 PHB p.13 point-buy limits the scores to the range 8-15. But if OP's using 77 points, *50 higher than the published method*, then they're obviously using some houseruled point-buy. (IOW, maybe there's no need for you to edit it out?)

Comment: Indeed an halfling can be used for the purpose :)

Comment: @nitsua60 for points i meant that the sum of all stats gives you 77 and this is right considering a base of 69 (lv 1 player) + 2 x 4 additional values given by the 5 level.. A normal LV 5 char has 77 as total value of it's stats, or "scores" as is written inside the manual. The reason why I go above 15 for a single stat is obtained because I'm over the lv 1

Comment: @user3450548 What 2x4 points at level 5? O.o

Comment: @BlueMoon93 PHB p.15 "When your character gains a level... allows you to increase your ability scores by 1 each or increasing one score by 2..."

Comment: That is gained when you reach specific levels in a single class. A rogue3/ranger3 has none, for example, only at level 4. Also, you gain only 2 points, not 2x4

Comment: @BlueMoon93 ouch, multiclassing is so terrible so :\\

Comment: I suggest that to go a bit more optimized, go variant human and use Sharpshooter feat.  And to go really sick, at 4/2, consider going warlock not ranger for two levels so that the devil's site range 120 feat works in character's favor.  Cast darkness and shoot out of it.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast so a Sharpshooter (instead ranger) Lv 4 / Warlock Lv 2 ? Seems cool but I have to ask my DM if i can use that archetype!

Comment: @user3450548 MIght want to run the numbers with that build, but you'd be able to add either another feat or another +2 by having achieved level 4 in one class.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast - The point buying was not clarified at that time.